# How to disable REST-Assured debug printing to console?

Tags: java, rest-assured

By default Rest-Assured is printing too much debug data to the console.

Can anyone tell how can I disable it?

Comment: remove the poject or atleast tell us what kind of logger you are using in which framework

Comment: I don't understand you question. i'm using stand alone log4j.

Comment: @DotanRaz Did you find a working solution? I am getting this issue as well. It is filling up my console logs, I am too using log4j.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell RestAssured what you want to log like this:

```
RestAssured
        .given()
        .log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL, true)
        .body(body)
        .post("URL")
        .then()
        .log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL, true)
        .extract()
        .jsonPath()
        .getObject("body", DTO.class)
```

and if something go wrong it print request/response info to console.

You can choose which part of request/response to log by specify value from **io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail** as ifValidationFails() first param.

If you want log request or response all the time use this

```
RestAssured
            .given()
            .log().<all|body|headers|etc>()
            .body(body)
            .post("URL")
            .then()
            .log().<all|body|headers|etc>()
            .extract()
            .jsonPath()
            .getObject("body", DTO.class)
```

log() after given() will config request logging

log() after then() will config response logging

You can find more helpful info here https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#logging

Answer (score 0):

remove line from  RestAssured

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://" + System.getProperty("API_HOST");
RestAssured.port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("API_PORT", "8080"));
```

or use

```
System.setProperty("http.maxConnections","100");
config = config().httpClient(httpClientConfig().reuseHttpClientInstance().httpClientFactory(
    () -> new SystemDefaultHttpClient()
));
```

Comment: this looks to be related to HTTPClient, not REST Assured... no?